# text wrapping in ipywidgets

Tags: word-wrap, ipywidgets

I can't seem to get my widgets to wrap text.

This code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

test_layout = widgets.Layout(
    border='1px solid black',
    flex_flow = 'row wrap',
    width = '200px')

test_string = 'test test test test test test test test test test'

test_label = widgets.Label(value = test_string, layout=test_layout)

test_label
```

Outputs:

[image: output]

What am I missing? I have tried lots of different things, but none of them have worked!

Comment: Increase  {width = '400px')}

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I used an HTML widget instead like this:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
widget = widgets.HTML(value= '<style>p{word-wrap: break-word}</style> <p>'+ [variable containing long text goes here] +' </p>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may increase `width = '400px')`